# Element that minimize the sum?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I found a problem that stated:

```
Let's consider a vector x = (x1, x2 ... xn) with real elements. 
1). Sort the vector  -- easy
2). Find a real number a so that sum ( abs (xi - a) ) is minim
```

I don't know if sorting the array helps, but for `2).` I thought i can do the aritmetic sum of all elements in the vector and say that the avg is the a we were looking for.

But that isn't correct. Example:

```
x = (1, 10, 10)
avg = [ 21/3 ] = 7 = a
sum = |1 - 7| + |10 - 7| + |10 - 7| = 6 + 3 + 3 = 12
```

but if we consider a = 10 we get

```
sum = |1 - 10| + |10 - 10| + |10 - 10| = 9 < 12
```

Another solution I could think of would be a brute force from the min element to the highest with a step of `i += 0.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) - rather then the average.

This is because what you are looking for is actually the [geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) - which happens to be the standard median if you have only one dimension (and you do).

The median can be found in `O(n)` using [Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) - so the sort is redundant.